# if or statement unexpected token

Tags: if-statement

I've attempting to write an in or statement, and in all honesty have never used one before.  I'm trying to use the following snippet of code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if(window.location.href.indexOf("invt") > -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("shopcart") > -1)) { // if URL contains invt or shopcart
   $('#carriage-promo').prop('id','newid');
     }
       });
```

But it keeps returning errors no matter what I try!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

( ) are unbalanced.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("invt") > -1 ||
   window.location.href.indexOf("shopcart") > -1)
```

I removed the last ) at the end of your if statement

Answer (score 2):

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("invt") > -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("shopcart") > -1))
```

You have one too many closing brackets `)`

Try:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("invt") > -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("shopcart") > -1)
```